# db.collection("articles").add results in ".default.collection is not a function"

Tags: javascript, firebase

Essentially I want to add a collection called "articles" with the following actors and store it in firebase.

I followed the doc for [uploading](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files) files to firebase. I was reading the doc for [adding](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data) data to firebase but it was a bit confusing and not sure how to implement it.

index.js (to view the other top half, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70297721/upload-to-firebase-error-storage-ref-is-not-a-function))

```
...
() => {
   getDownloadURL(upload.snapshot.ref).then((downloadURL) => {
    db.collection("articles").add({
      actor: {
        description: payload.user.email,
        title: payload.user.displayName,
        date: payload.timestamp,
        image: payload.user.photoURL,
        },
        video: payload.video,
        sharedImg: downloadURL,
        comments: 0,
        description: payload.description,
       });
   });
}
```

However, whenever I run this code, I get "Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): *firebase__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0*_.default.collection is not a function."

firebase.js

```
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { getAuth, GoogleAuthProvider } from 'firebase/auth';
import { getStorage } from "firebase/storage";
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";

const firebaseConfig = {
...
}

const firebaseApp = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const db = getFirestore(firebaseApp);
const auth = getAuth();
const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider();
const storage = getStorage(firebaseApp);
  
export { auth, provider, storage };
export default db;
```

Any advise as to what is going wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Same as on your previous question, since you're using the v9 syntax to import specific functions, you can no longer call methods on `db` or a `CollectionReference`.

The equivalent of your snippet in the v9 modular syntax is:

```
const collectionRef = collection(db, "articles")
addDoc(collectionRef, { ... })
```

I strongly recommend that you spend some time in the Firebase documentation on [writing data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#web-version-9) and in the [upgrade guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade) to get familiar with how the syntax in your existing code maps to the new syntax.

---

If you don't want to upgrade your code, you can also consider [using the `compat` paths](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade#update_imports_to_v9_compat) of the v9 SDKs.